# Text on image shrinks when I resize the browser

Tags: html, css

I have text written on the image. When I resize the browser, the text shrinks.
Why is this happening? Is there a way to keep the text from shrinking when I resize the browser?

```css
 #center p {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   left: 150px;
   top: 800px;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
 }
 #center1 p {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   top: 820px;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
 }
 #center2 p {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   left: 450px;
   font-size: 20px;
   top: 840px;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
 }
 #center3 p {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   top: 880px;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
 }
 #center4 p {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   top: 900px;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
 }
 #center5 p {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   left: 450px;
   font-size: 20px;
   top: 920px;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
 }
 #center img {
   width: 100%
 }
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <img id="img" src="images/1.jpg" alt="img" width="1280">


  <p>
    In 2050, we are projected to have 9 billion on this planet. These people will eat and drink just like we do..</p>
  <div id="center1">
    <p>requiring a doubling of food production. But food and water security already are the largest challenges for a</p>
  </div>

  <div id="center2">
    <p>thriving global population.</p>
  </div>





  <div id="center3">
    <p>Drops and Crops is a network of stusome text some text some text some text some text some tesxt some text to tackle this</p>
  </div>
  <div id="center4">
    <p>great challenge of our some text some text some text some text some textby the Water</p>
  </div>


  <div id="center5">
    <p>for Food Institut.</p>
  </div>



</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLyd6zv1/

Comment: What you mean the text shrink? ... That it overlaps?

Comment: No, I imagine OP has an image with text on it, and since OP has the image to have a 100% width, the width obviously goes up or down depending on viewport size - so if OP makes it smaller, the text in the image will follow suit.

Comment: @LGSon Yes text overlaps with each other

Comment: That is because you use `position absolute`. Remove that and let text flow normal.

Comment: @LGSon yes, it doesn't overlap But If I remove position- absolute then text doesn't go on image.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule for "#center img" is telling it to have 100% width so it stretches it out no matter what the size of the viewport is. Remove that.

Comment: Doesn't made any difference

Comment: Then you aren't describing your problem correctly - looking on LGSon's answer confirms that for me.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The image is not showing up, but I would add max-width:100% in addition to width:100% on #center img. Also, not sure if you are using bootstrap, but you should also use the img-responsive class in html to scale the image according to browser width.

Comment: Not using Bootstrap. SImple HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirements but you shouldn't need a new `div` for every new line of text, nor a `p` for that matter.

Everyone else is correct that your CSS styles are set to be too strict and will bunch up your text.  Try putting all of the content in one `div`, and if you need the image to be just a background set

`background-image: url(url-of-your-image.png);`

Maybe this updated fiddle will help https://jsfiddle.net/pLyd6zv1/2/

Comment: @plasticpis     good work.  I need to write the text in paragraphs. if I do so it overlaps

Comment: If you need to separate the lines you can try line breaks `<br>` or putting each line into a `div` or `span` with a `margin`;

Please accept my response if it answers your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pLyd6zv1/3/ with line breaks.  This does not give you control over how much space but it is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add your text in a wrapper and set that one to `position: absolute`

*In below I removed all `position: absolute` and `top: ??px` for the `p` element and added the commented rules and the `<div class="wrap">` element in the markup.*

*To remove space between the `p` elements, I added `margin: 0;` to the `#center p`*

```css
#center {                /*  added rule   */
  position: relative;
}
#center img {
  width:100%;
}
#center .wrap {          /*  added rule   */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#center p {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 150px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  margin: 0;                      /* added prop. to remove space */
}
#center1 p {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
#center2 p {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  left:450px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
#center3 p {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
#center4 p {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
#center5 p {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  left:450px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <img id="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/nature/2" alt="img" width="1280">

  <div class="wrap">
    <p>
      In 2050, we are projected to have 9 billion on this planet. These people will eat and drink just like we do..</p>
    <div id="center1"><p> requiring a doubling of food production. But food and water security already are the largest challenges for a</p></div>

    <div id="center2"><p> thriving global population.</p></div>

    <div id="center3"> <p>Drops and Crops is a network of stusome text some text some text some text some text some tesxt some text to tackle this</p></div>
    <div id="center4"><p> great challenge of our some text some text some text some text some textby the Water</p></div>

    <div id="center5"><p>         for Food Institut.</p></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need to remove spacing gap between lines. This code created some spacing gap between the lines.